# SSRS Report XML export

Tags: reporting-services

When we export an SSRS report as an XML, the generated XML report has fully qualified internal domain name of the reporting server.
need to come up with a solution , wherein the generated XML should contain only the report data without the details of the reporting server.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to remove the domain from the XML. This is the default and there aren't any properties to control it.

> Attaching the name prefix is a normal behavior when you export the
>   report to XML file, as name conflicts in XML can easily be avoided
>   using a name prefix

[[MSFT] MSDN Community Support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1784c52-d6cf-4d91-bc73-28cf573f8f3b/how-to-remove-report-schema-location-and-xmlns-from-xml-format-report?forum=sqlreportingservices)

The suggestion is to create a custom rendering extension.

Unfortunately, MS Docs notes that:

> Writing a custom rendering extension is difficult. A rendering
>   extension must typically support all possible combinations of report
>   elements and requires that you implement hundreds of classes,
>   interfaces, methods, and properties.

[MS Docs - Rendering Extensions Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/rendering-extension/rendering-extensions-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)